# Is hibernatemode 25 broken on macOS High Sierra and can it be fixed?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, sleep-wake, memory, hibernate

Following the instructions on [this article](https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-hibernate-a-mac--cms-23235), I've had hibernatemode 25 working since Sierra, El Capitan, and probably Yosemite. It's set via:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

Beforehand, it worked like this:

1. If MacBook is plugged in and you click Sleep, it goes into normal sleep. and wakes normally.
2. If MacBook is unplugged, memory would be saved to persistent storage and the laptop would shut down.
3. Plugging the MacBook back in *or* pressing keys on the keyboard would show your login screen, but with a white overlay and a loading circle. When the memory is finished loading it allows you to log in.

Now what it does is:

1. Drains battery power.
2. Crashes the laptop.

Every time I've tried to resume my MacBook from Hibernate, plugging it in or pressing keys doesn't work. I press the power button and it turns out that the entire MacBook has crashed! It's done this about 3 times now and I'm tired of losing my work.

I use Hibernate on Windows profusely and as my MacBook gets older and slower, I don't want to be reopening all of my applications every day. If it could work just like Windows, it would be as good as Windows.

Comment: If it is, https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know where I could go to report bugs. I'll do that today.

Comment: Ouch, looks like my Apple ID [has to be a developer account](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76368) if I want to submit a bug report that way. It looks like I'll have to contact support.

Comment: It's free to register for a developer account. [Take a look at this page](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/), and note the free tier on the chart at the bottom.

Comment: Ah, I see what they're doing. They're trying to hide the free tier _way_ down at the bottom under the paid tiers. I registered my Apple ID as a developer with ease and I have a draft of the issue now. I just have to simulate the battery drain when I get home and submit a sysdiagnose.