# Is "pmset hibernatemode 25" still broken in Monterey?

Tags: macos, monterey, pmset, sleep-wake

I executed `pmset hibernatemode 25` on my Macbook Pro 16" (Intel) running MacOS Monterey but it didn't seem to work. Searching here revealed several similar questions for

[High Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311041/is-hibernatemode-25-broken-on-macos-high-sierra-and-can-it-be-fixed)

[Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395602/macos-catalina-hibernatemode-25-invalid)

[Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352504/macos-mojave-hibernatemode-25-dark-wake-sleep-wake)

– and none of them had a satisfactory answer (or any answer at all).

What is the current state of this feature? Broken? Is there anyone who can confirm that it works for them in Monterey (or any other version of MacOS)? How did you do it? Can you post your configuration?

In case you have the same problem, you can report it to Apple at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/ if you have a developers account (they are free).

Comment: I successfully set `sudo pmset hibernatemode 25` on a Monterey 12.4, MacBook Air M1 2020.  Caused a login screen (which may have been my settings) when restarting (with a startup progress bar). Setting it back to hibernatemode 3 doesn't remove the /var/vm/sleepimage mode, which can be removed in a sudo command, folowed by touching the now removed file. Subsequently invoking sleep will not fill the file (which was 1 GiB for an 8G SDRAM/256G SDD).

Comment: @user16145658 Do you experience "slow wake ups" after sleep? That is what I mostly am interested in (i.e., to save electricity).

Comment: A wake from hibernation also involves loading the RAM image from the file unlike waking from sleep where the RAM is kept powered up. The idea being hibernation saves power. It's about the same as booting up from powerdown. You can as easily shutdown (fast with APFS and SSD).

Comment: Yes, and loading RAM from a file takes a while. Powering down is not an option because you lose state (e.g., what programs are open with what documents etc).

Comment: There's a persistent setting invoked by checking `Reopen windows when logging back in` when using the Apple Shut Down menu item. (And Apple would explain it's not there fault if 3rd party software doesn't adhere to the protocols for saving and restoring state.)